# Why charged particles moving in an electric field deflect less at higher velocity?

Tags: electromagnetism, classical-mechanics, classical-electrodynamics

According to coloumb's law, particles of the same charge should experience the same force, however, when moving at higher velocities, they deflect less.

Can this be explained in terms of classical mechanics?

Answer (score 2):

If the particles momentum $mV$ and $mv$ with $V>v$ undergo the same impulse $F\Delta t$ and thus change in momentum by the same amount $\Delta p$ then the change in direction is smaller for the faster particle as shown in the diagram below with $\beta < \alpha$.

[image]

A smaller impulse acting on the faster particle will result in an even smaller change in direction.

Answer (score 1):

Easily. Consider the particles going through a region of electric field of finite extent. If the particles are moving faster they will pass through the region in a shorter time. Therefore their change in momentum, and hence their change in velocity, will be less.

Suppose that the electric field is in the $y$ direction and is of uniform magnitude $E_y$ over a region extending an x-wise distant $\Delta x.$ Particles of charge $q$, moving with velocity $v_x$ in the $x$ direction will experience a force $qE_y$ in the $y$ direction for a time $\Delta t$ given by$$\Delta t=\frac{\Delta x}{v_x}.$$ Therefore their change in momentum is given by$$qE_y \frac{\Delta x}{v_x}=m \Delta v_y$$
You'll see that the deflection, as measured by their acquired $y$ velocity component, $\Delta v_y,$ is inversely proportional to the entry velocity, $v_x.$

This applies at particle speeds much less than *c*, as unmodified Newtonian dynamics applies. For particle speeds that aren't negligible compared to *c*, we can fix things (provided that $v_y<<v_x)$ by inserting a gamma factor, giving
$$qE_y \frac{\Delta x}{v_x}=m\gamma \Delta v_y$$
in which $\gamma=(1-\frac{v_{x}^2+v_{y}^2}{c^2})^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ This will further lower the deflection for faster particles.